# Implementing an Employee Schedule in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mongodb, schedule

Hi Stackoverflow Family,

So this is a pretty big question; be prepared to read quite a bit. 
Basically my team and I working on an Employee scheduling application (we're already well into it, so please nothing about changing our stack or anything like that). Anyways, we're building this with PHP, Mongo, JavaScript, JQuery, and Bootstrap; and I'm working more on the db side of things.

What I really want to find out after asking this question is to see if my current approach to the db is right; I've basically created several collections and documents that reference each other in order to access or reference specific data that I'm looking for. If that doesn't really make sense check out my schema below:

**Employee Collection - Contains indexes such as name, employeeNumber, address, etc, employee availability, position & department.**
(My issue here is I want it to reference other collections which contain their Shift information, but I can only really do that when I insert a document).

**Shift Collection - Contains indexes such as shiftNumber, shiftStartTime, endTime** (This collection, I basically want to reference to employee, such that for creating each employee I have their shift time connected to it).

**Schedule Collection ** - Now for the Schedule collection, this is the one that confuses me the most; I basically want our Calendar UI to be able to look through our schedule collection and be able to pull all the shifts in a certain day, or in a specific week. But I have no idea as to how I can approach this from the backend.

So far what I've done with the Schedule Collection is that I've mathematically created a Calendar year and placed that within the Schedule; basically it contains a document called Year, and in that Year it contains every day of the week with information such as day number, week number, leapYear, etc.

Anyways, I hope this is enough information; my main confusion is the with the main schedule, I think I nearly have the Employee collection functioning properly since it references the Department class with no issues. I just mainly can't figure out how to implement a full schedule in mongo!

Thanks guys!

Comment: Maybe you dont need the Schedule Collection.You can add date field in the Shift Collection itself, & then the Calendar UI can query based entirely on the date field.

Comment: Thanks! Believe it or not your small comment changed my project completely, and I figured out the problem! Just submitted this project (my capstone) last week! Thank you :)